# Is it illegal to design a typographic quote based on a book quote/lyric, then sell it as a print?

Tags: typography, copyright

FYI I'm in Australia so laws will probably differ to that in America.

I'm curious however as there are heaps of great typographical designs of quotes...but is it illegal to make profits off your design selling them as prints etc? Or would it be ok to add the author's name as part of the design?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a question best asked to a lawyer..

I would check to see who owns the copyright.  If the copyrighted quote is still current ask for rights.  That said they might (copyright owner) request you to add the author, pay some commission on the sales, buy a timed limit usage or an X amount of prints that they will allow for a given time frame.  You could always check to see if the copyright expired and if its up for fair use but again, consult a lawyer in your area.

Might help for you to check [copyright.gov](http://www.copyright.gov/) or in your case [Australian Copyright Council](http://www.copyright.org.au/)

You may find this helpful:

"[Quotes & Extracts](http://www.copyright.org.au/admin/cms-acc1/_images/92076231252708b2107369.pdf)" from "[Find an Answer](http://www.copyright.org.au/find-an-answer/browse-by-a-z/)"